# linq to datatable incorrect column calculation

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Trying to calculate a column value with linq. It sums correctly but produces incorrect value when dividing or multiplying. Example is below.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dtWidgets = Get_widgets();   
        DataTable dtHits = Get_hits();

        var hit_rate =
        from w in dtWidgets.AsEnumerable()
        join h in dtHits.AsEnumerable()
            on w[0] equals h[0]
        select new
        {
            Date = w.Field<DateTime>("calendar_date"),
            Widgets = w.Field<int>("widgets"),
            Hits = h.Field<int>("hits"),
            TestSum = w.Field<int>("widgets")+h.Field<int>("hits"),
            TestMult = w.Field<int>("widgets") * h.Field<int>("hits")
        };

        gvWidgets.DataSource = dtWidgets;
        gvWidgets.DataBind();

        gvHits.DataSource = dtHits;
        gvHits.DataBind();

        gvLinq.DataSource = hit_rate.ToArray();
        gvLinq.DataBind();

    }

    static DataTable Get_widgets()
    {
        DataTable widgets = new DataTable();
        widgets.Columns.Add("calendar_date", typeof(DateTime));
        widgets.Columns.Add("widgets", typeof(int));

        widgets.Rows.Add("05/15/2012", 200000);
        widgets.Rows.Add("05/16/2012", 210000);
        return widgets;
    }

    static DataTable Get_hits()
    {
        DataTable hits = new DataTable();
        hits.Columns.Add("calendar_date", typeof(DateTime));
        hits.Columns.Add("hits", typeof(int));

        hits.Rows.Add("05/15/2012", 100000000);
        hits.Rows.Add("05/16/2012", 120000000);
        return hits;
    }
}
```

Returns:

Date                   Widgets Hits     TestSum   TestMult

5/15/2012 12:00:00 AM 200000 100000000 100200000 -1662697472

5/16/2012 12:00:00 AM 210000 120000000 120210000 1426874368

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I where you, I would look at the limit of int in c#... (2147483647)

Try with long (= Int64)

```
20000000000000 
>
2147483647
```

Comment: Thanks!  A follow up to this one: It now multiplies correctly but divison shows 0.00 when the number is less than 0. Any ideas on that?  TestHitRate = w.Field<Int64>("widgets") / h.Field<Int64>("hits")

Comment: Disregard, I found it using Decimal

Answer (score 1):

Given the example numbers you have listed underneath the code, it looks like you're getting integer overflow. Try making the field type Int64.